# For loop wildcard matching in batch script

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, wildcard

I'm writing a batch script that is supposed to find all files in a directory of type **.exp** and rename them.  Everything is working except the FOR loop, because I can't seem to get the wildcard matching to find the proper set of files.

If I write:

```
for /F %%x in (*.exp) do (echo %%x)
```

Result is:

```
The system cannot find the file *.exp
```

If I write:

```
for /F %%x in ("*.exp") do (
echo %%x
echo %%~nx.exp
)
```

Result is:

```
*.exp
expectedfilename1.exp
```

but the loop only runs once and stops at the first file.

Every online example I've seen uses one of these formats, so I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.  Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

For %%x in (*.exp) do (echo %%x)

Or

For /f "tokens=*" %%x in ('dir /b *.exp') do (echo %%x)

Comment: Figured it out just before I saw your answer, but you're also right.
It was that sneaky little /F :) Problem solved.